# Convergence of sum of independent gaussian random variables N(0,1/2^i)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given $Z_i$ are independent gaussian random variables with $Z_i $~$N(0,\frac{1}{2^i})$, does $X_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}Z_j$ converge in mean square sense. I know that it converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$. But I am not able to prove or disprove the convergence in mean square sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$
X_n^2=\sum_{j=1}^n Z_j^2+\sum_{i,j:i\neq j} Z_iZ_j.
$$